# No sé porque no puedo usar el método de mi objeto hijo tras la herencia

Tags: poo, herencia, javascript-objeto

No puedo usar el método de mi objeto hijo

---

objeto padre con el que intento emular niveles de privacidad

```
var Developer = (function(){
        var priv = new WeakMap()
        var _ = function(instance){return priv.get(instance)}

        function DeveloperClass(name, surname){
            var privateMembers = {name:'', surname:''}
            priv.set(this, privateMembers)

            _(this).name = name
            _(this).surname = surname

            console.log(_(this).surname)

            this.languajes = []
        }
        DeveloperClass.prototype.insertLanguage = function(languaje){
            this.languajes.push(languaje)
        }
        return DeveloperClass

    }())
```

---

objeto hijo

```
    var Student = (function(){

        function StudentClass(name, surname, college){
            Developer.call(this,name, surname)
            this.college = college
        }

        // ¿Porqué no puedo usar este método?
        StudentClass.prototype.showInformation = function(){
            return "hello"
        }
        return StudentClass
    }())
```

---

creamos la herencia

```
    Student.prototype = Object.create(Developer.prototype)
    Student.prototype.constructor  = Student
```

---

instanciamos la el objeto hijo, la instacia se crea sin problemas

```
    var alejandro = new Student('Jonathan', 'Alejandro','UNAJ')
```

---

pero llamo al metodo que quiero usar del objeto hijo y resulta function is not defined

```
    console.log(alejandro.showInformation())
```